# running trained convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

So here is my question. I have trained a convolutional neural network to classify images into two classes using tensorflow. I am now wondering how to use the weights from that neural network and test it on an unlabeled random image. Is there a function in tensorflow to do that or should I run the convolution on my own now?

Comment: Could you provide some example of the code that you use?

Comment: @MiriamFarber what part would you need? because there is a lot of code... i can provide the [github page](https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_make_a_tensorflow_image_classifier_LIVE/blob/master/demonotes.ipynb) I used as a reference. basically, the code is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you finished training, you can create

```
feed_dict_unlabeled = {x: x_unlabeled}
```

Now, using `y_pred_cls` that is defined in your code as follows:

```
y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, dimension=1)
```

you can do

`y_labels = session.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict=feed_dict_unlabeled)`

to find the labels of the unlabeled data.

In addition, here is a discussion about similar scenario which you may find helpful: [Python/Tensorflow - I have trained the convolutional neural network, how to test it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031674/python-tensorflow-i-have-trained-the-convolutional-neural-network-how-to-test/43032136#43032136)

Comment: Is x_unlabeled an image as a float array?

Comment: It should be in the same format as x_batch from feed_dict_train = {x: x_batch, y_true: y_true_batch}, except of the quantities. That is, the number of images in x_batch and x_unlabeled may be different, but other than that they should be in the same format, as both of them correspond to the same placeholder.